# Heroku ACM problems – stuck at "DNS verified", sites down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

Our Heroku application initially had $20/m paid SSL add on –– we still have this installed

At some point we switched to the letsencrypt-rails-heroku gem –– this appeared to be working fine up until last night when our certs expired and for some reason failed to renew

I attempted to switch to Heroku's new Automated Certificate Management service, which got stuck at "DNS Verified" and never progressed to "Ok".

I then attempted to update the letsencrypt-rails-heroku gem and manually renew –– the command appeared to work but produced no results in heroku certs

I once again enabled ACM, and am once again stuck at "DNS Verified"

Heroku support appears to now primarily a paid offering which my client has not yet purchased and Heroku des not seem to have any troubleshooting tips to debug.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Same issue here - ACM is either responding with "waiting" or "ok" in status when using certs:auto and I get ssl errors trying to connect to my server.Could be related to the rate limits on letsencrypt (if you have many failing subdomains) but not sure.

Comment: @Michael Schmitz no we didn't. Support told me that they had bugs with their ACM system that they were trying to work out, and also that they were hitting limits with Let's Encrypt. They suggested that I try again the following month when their limits had been reset but then wrote and told me that maybe I should hold off as they still had problems on their end.  I switched back to using the heroku let's encrypt gem for the time being.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've spent Thursday night, Friday, Saturday and early Sunday on the SSL part and finally just purchased a cert somewhere else. Shame it's not working yet, huge boon for mankind. Good luck with everything.